# Weird test in linear regression model

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, linear-regression

At my uni on statistics course I was given some tasks to solve and here is one I have been struggling with for quite a while:

Let $\hat{\beta}$ be the least squares estimator in linear model $Y = X \beta + \epsilon$ with $p$ predictors and $n$ observations, $$\text{let }I(a) = \dfrac{(a^T\hat{\beta})^2}{s^2a^T(X^TX)^{-1}a}\text{ and }I = \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}^p}I(a)\text{, where }s^2=SSE/(n-p)\text{ and }a\in \mathbb{R}^p.$$
Now I am supposed to interpret $I(a)$ value and come up with $H_0$ hypothesis which can be tested using $I$ as test statistic. To be honest I have no idea how to do both of it. I was trying to look at $a^T\hat{\beta}$ as on prediction of trained model for $a$, but the denominator of $I(a)$ doesn't really make sense to me. I also tried substituting $\hat{\beta}$ with $(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ and then replacing $Y$ with $X \beta + \epsilon$ but this also didn't lead me anywhere. I have, of course, searched for different tests which are preformed in linear model but nothing similar to $I$ statistic came out.

Comment: If $B$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrix and $x,d$ are real vectors, can you find $\max_{x\ne 0}\frac{(x^T d)^2}{x^TBx}$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, nothing other than derivation comes to my mind, unfortunately.  But this will be a bit hard, because fraction is not necessarily convex and second derivative check is needed. Is there a way to solve this without derivatives?

Comment: It can be done with a generalization of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, namely $(x^T d)^2\le (x^TBx)(d^TB^{-1}d)$. To prove this, apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $B^{1/2}x$ and $B^{-1/2}d$. I will let you fill in the details and justify why this result is applicable in your case.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, thank you very much for so quick response, your hint will definitely bring some fresh air to this.